# What is best practice for placing async/await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<JsonResult<LoginStatus>> Login(LoginDTO loginDTO)
{
    var result = new JsonResult<LoginStatus>();

    try
    {
        var signIn = SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginDTO.Username, loginDTO.Password, loginDTO.IsPersistent, false); // or any async method.

        result.Success = true;

        await signIn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Success = false;
        result.Error = ex;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I can change it like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult<LoginStatus>> Login(LoginDTO loginDTO)
{
    var result = new JsonResult<LoginStatus>();

    try
    {
        await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginDTO.Username, loginDTO.Password, loginDTO.IsPersistent, false); // or any async method.

        result.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Success = false;
        result.Error = ex;
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Is there any difference (performance or anything) between them? and which one is the best Practice?**

Comment: There is not really any difference. Shouldn't PasswordSignInAsync rather return a boolean than throw exception? And if you throw exception dont show want to catch the specific exception related to not being able to sign in, now you catch all.

Comment: Did you measure performance? How often do you have to login anyway that this would matter?

Comment: @PepitoSh my question is not about Login, I mean any **async** method..

Comment: In first example you set result as successful before it is actually successful. While it's no big difference in both examples, personally I would use the second one - logic is correct and it will work if you decide to remove try/catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no appreciable difference

- In the first, you are returning a `Task` from `PasswordSignInAsync` assigning `result.Success = true` and then awaiting the task
- In the second, you are awaiting the the `PasswordSignInAsync` `Task`, and if it doesn't throw you assign `result.Success = true`

If anything, the second version is cleaner and you are saving a tiny bit of `IL` by potentially not performing a redundant assignment. All-in-all, i don't expect any performance difference and it comes down to fashion sense

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere within `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` is an await. In your first method you already assign the result before you really know whether the SignIn was successful or not. If you sign if fails after that, your assignment would be futile.

So to know whether you should use the first or the latter method depends on how often you expect this method to fail. Normally, exception handling is quite expensive. therefore they should only be used if they are expected to happen seldom, especially in relation to the time needed to repair the problem that caused the exception.

If that is the case, then you could use both methods. Maybe the first one is a few computer ticks faster. If would probably be even faster if you'd make sure that after construction your JsonResult would already have a success value:

```
var result = new JsonResult() {Success = true;}
```

Only change it to false in your catch block